# .xprofile checking if the output display exists

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

So I have a laptop and a external monitor which I often use at home. In order the external monitor displays the proper resolution, I added a `.xprofile` file in my home directory which contains:

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

This works every time I boot my laptop with the external monitor plugged in. But when the monitor isn't plugged in and I am using only the laptop monitor, an error window shows up and says that it could not find the output display, i.e. `DP-1`.

Is it possible to do some checks before running the `.xprofile`, for example if the display exists or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the name of your device, in your case "DP-1," you can simply add this code around the commands you want to execute in your .xprofile file; it will check if "DP-1" is connected.

```
if xrandr --query | grep '^DP-1 connected'; then
  # Your code here
fi
```

If you are unsure which device you want to check, run `xrandr --query` in your terminal, and it will display all of them.